# Django Many To Many table filter makes too many sql queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm filtering my `Department` model with django_filters. But it makes too many queries. How can I fix it?

```
# models.py

class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Branches"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(Branch, related_name="department")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

_

```
# views.py

class DepartmentListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = DepartmentFilter
```

_

```
# serializers.py

class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = "__all__"
```

_

```
# filters.py

class DepartmentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    branch = filters.CharFilter(field_name="branch__id", lookup_expr="in")

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = "__all__"
```

[image: Screen of django_toolbar]

[image]

Comment: Share the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *filtering*, but with *serializing*: your serializer forces to fetch the related `Branch`es for each `Department` individually, you can fetch these all in one extra query with:

```
class DepartmentListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Department.objects.prefetch_related('branch')
    serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = DepartmentFilter
```

---

> **Note**: Since a `ManyToManyField` refers to a *collection* of elements,
> `ManyToManyField`s are normally given a *plural* name. You thus might want
> to consider renaming <s>`branch`</s> to `branches`.